# How to get rid of special character in Netezza columns

Tags: sql, special-characters, talend, netezza

I am transferring data from one Netezza database to another using Talend, an ETL tool. When I pull data from a varchar(30) field and try to put it in the new database's varchar(30) field, it gives an error saying it's too long. Logs show the field has whitespace at the end followed by a square, representing some character I can't figure out. I attached a screenshot of the logs below. I have tried writing SQL to pull this field and replace what I thought was a CRLF, but no luck. When I do a select on the field and get the length, it has a few extra characters than what you see, so something is there and I want to get rid of it. Trimming does not do anything.

This SQL does not return a length shorter than simply doing length() on the column itself. Does anyone know what else it could be?

```
 SELECT   LENGTH(trim(translate(TRANSLATE(<column>, chr(13), ''), chr(10), ''))) as len_modified
```

[image: Snapshot of the logs]

Note that the last column in the logs, where you see a square in brackets, is supposed to show the last character examined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the data to a larger target table size that works.  If 30 character data put it in a 500 character table.  Get it to work.  Then look through character by character on the fields that are the longest to determine what character is being added.  Use commands like ascii() to determine the ascii value of the individual characters and the beginning and end.  Most likely you are getting some additional character in the beginning or the end.  Determine what the extra character data is and then write code to remove it or to never load it so that it fits in the 30 character column.  Or just leave your target column with longer and include the additional characters.  For example Varchar(30) becomes Varchar(32) (waste the space but don't alter the data as it comes in to you).

Comment: Your suggestion of using the ascii function was what helped me realize it was a non-breaking space, unicode value 160. I just ran the ascii function on the column using the character at the 29th index (using the substring function). I have been able to remove it using the translate function and chr(160). Thanks!!

Comment: Not a problem I have come across this same problem 20+ times.  This was my solution that so far has worked every time for me.  There are lists of other characters many of them that appear invisible that you will potentially see this issue on.